# Is node-red-ui-node-table supported on IBM Cloud, how does it work?

Tags: node-red

Is saw https://discourse.nodered.org/t/examples-for-node-red-node-ui-table/14256.

and tried the code snippet mentioned @ 14/51.

It didn't work on IBM Cloud and on my Mac, although I could install the node. No messages in debug nor log (locally).

I wonder if there any pre-reqs, working examples?

**Edit** after installing installing latest dashboard on local machine:

```
$ node-red
10 Oct 14:47:28 - [info] 

Welcome to Node-RED
===================

10 Oct 14:47:28 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.18.4
10 Oct 14:47:28 - [info] Node.js  version: v8.12.0
10 Oct 14:47:28 - [info] Darwin 18.7.0 x64 LE
10 Oct 14:47:29 - [info] Loading palette nodes
10 Oct 14:47:37 - [info] Dashboard version 2.8.2 started at /ui
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [warn] [node-red/rpi-gpio] Info : Ignoring Raspberry Pi specific node
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [warn] [node-red-contrib-homekit/homekit] Error: The module '/Users/jps/.node-red/node_modules/mdns/build/Release/dns_sd_bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [warn] [node-red-contrib-hyperledger-composer/hperledger-composer] 'hyperledger-composer-in' already registered by module node-red-contrib-composer
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [warn] [node-red-node-sensortag/sensorTag] Error: The module '/Users/jps/.node-red/node_modules/xpc-connection/build/Release/binding.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 48. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [info] Settings file  : /Users/jps/.node-red/settings.js
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [info] User directory : /Users/jps/.node-red
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [warn] Projects disabled : set editorTheme.projects.enabled=true to enable
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [info] Flows file     : /Users/jps/.node-red/flows_MacBook-Pro-3.fritz.box.json
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [info] Starting flows
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [error] [telegram bot:4316da31.0f7c94] Configuration data for webhook is missing. Defaulting to polling mode.
10 Oct 14:47:40 - [info] [mosca in:c2c2553a.5302a8] Binding mosca mqtt server on port: 1884
TypeError: RED.require is not a function
    at new TableNode (/Users/jps/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-node-ui-table/node.js:48:30)
    at createNode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/flows/Flow.js:305:18)
    at Flow.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/flows/Flow.js:89:35)
```

**Output after wipe/reinstall/restart of Node-RED**

```
10 Oct 20:56:19 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.18.4
10 Oct 20:56:19 - [info] Node.js  version: v8.12.0
10 Oct 20:56:19 - [info] Darwin 18.7.0 x64 LE
10 Oct 20:56:19 - [info] Loading palette nodes
...
10 Oct 21:00:53 - [info] Starting flows
TypeError: RED.require is not a function
    at new TableNode (/Users/jps/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-node-ui-table/node.js:48:30)
    at createNode (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/flows/Flow.js:305:18)
    at Flow.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/flows/Flow.js:89:35)
    at start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/flows/index.js:307:29)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red/runtime/nodes/flows/index.js:144:21
    at tryCatchReject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:845:30)
    at runContinuation1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:804:4)
    at Fulfilled.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:592:4)
    at Pending.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/when/lib/makePromise.js:483:13)
    at Scheduler._drain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/node_modules/when/lib/Scheduler.js:62:19)
10 Oct 21:00:53 - [info] Started flows
10 Oct 21:01:21 - [info] Stopping flows
10 Oct 21:01:21 - [info] Stopped flows
```

On the dashboard there's an empty page and a Connection lost message flashing.

Comment: What version of `node-red-dashboard` do you have installed?

Comment: sorry, don't know how to determine the version, I installed latest version on local machine using npm i node-red-dashboard. I can see the table under "Tabs & Links" in the layout pane, but the dashboard remains empty (Please add some UI nodes...)

Comment: You can check the installed version from the palette manager

Comment: Look at the top of the trace you just posted, you are still running Node-RED version 0.18.4

Comment: the dashboard version is 2.17.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the additional packages via Manage Palette, use the IBM Cloud Toolchain and the git repository in IBM Cloud to add the following packages to the package.json. Commit the change, and the IBM Cloud Continuous Delivery toolchain will build and deploy the Cloud Foundry application.

```
"node-red-node-ui-table":"0.x",
"node-red-dashboard":"2.x",
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.18.x of Node-RED is VERY VERY out of date.

Version 1.0.1 was recently released, you will need to upgrade for the `node-red-ui-node-table` to work.

The dashboard version is also listed in the trace ouput, it's 2.8.2, this is also very old, the current is 2.17.1 and you need to be on at least 2.10.0 to support extra dashboard nodes.

After upgrading you should also run `npm rebuild` in `/Users/jps/.node-red` to fix the issues listed in the trace with the homekit nodes.

Comment: I did (1)  Node-RED upgrade to 1.0.1 (per npm show), (2) npm build , (3) node-red, it crashes at startup (Uncaught Exception:
10 Oct 19:22:50 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined). Node-RED, Dashboard etc. versions there are the same as above

Comment: wiped (.node-red directory) and reinstalled Node-RED, still not working, only a flashing Connection lost message

Comment: I added 1 regular dashboard node to the flow which I can see now (no flashing message), but still no table content

Comment: You still haven't shown any evidence that you are running Node-RED v1.0.1 and not still 0.18.4

Comment: Exactly, I wonder why it shows 0.18.4 even after a successful (I think) upgrade (+ node-red@1.0.1 updated 2 packages in 16.133s)?

Comment: We can't answer that, because we have no idea how you installed Node-RED to start with or what you did to upgrade.

Comment: I deleted the .node-red directory with the old Node-RED files and then I used sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red on macOS 10.14.6. My flow doesn't work on IBM Cloud Node-RED instance either, that I created yesterday. This is the flow https://ibm.box.com/s/ytt2hom7b9zlfikxsyjfjvvcnf3w3mpn, maybe it's not correct. Would be interested in any other working flow.

Comment: I managed to get the ui-table node running under Docker on my Mac. The same flow isn't running under IBM Cloud (created the instance today, latest version, I assume): That is what I found on the log: Node.js version: v12.13.0, 8 Feb 12:13:55 - [info] Dashboard version 2.19.4 started at /ui, Error: Cannot find module 'node-red-dashboard'. at new TableNode (/home/vcap/app/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-node-ui-table/node.js:48:30). Not sure what else to look for.

Comment: also, when I copy/pasted the flows from Mac to IBM Cloud I had to create the whole Dashboard Layout structure , Tabs & Links again, it was not copied. Not sure, if that is a bug.